# Use slug rather than id for $post->post_parent?

Tags: conditional-tags

Is there a way that, when using $post->post_parent in a conditional, the parent slug can be used rather than the parent id?

I'm using the code below to prepend some page/post titles with parent info, and want to replace the id with the slug/name of the parent.

```
elseif ( is_page('notes') || '2' == $post->post_parent ||   is_singular('post'))
{ $title['title'] = 'Notes: ' . $title['title'];}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also get slug from direct post parent id like:

```
$parent_id   = $post->post_parent;
$post_parent_slug = get_post_field( 'post_name', $parent_id );
```

Now you can replace:

```
'2' == $post->post_parent
```

to

```
'notes' == $post_parent_slug
```

Try this.

Comment: Thanks. I've since added to my original question, and I don't know enough to be able to use your suggestion.